# How to implement Binding for ImageButtons so that the image is only displayed once the image is loaded?

Tags: c#, xamarin, data-binding, binding, runtime

I have two ImageButtons which should switch their images when clicked.

```
<ImageButton
      Grid.Column="15"
      Grid.Row="20"
      Clicked="Clicked"
      Source="{Binding Game[0], Converter={StaticResource StringToSourceConverter}}"
       >
</ImageButton>

<ImageButton
      Grid.Column="15"
      Grid.Row="20"
      Clicked="Clicked"
      Source="{Binding Game[1], Converter={StaticResource StringToSourceConverter}}"
       >
</ImageButton>
```

The Clicked method swaps the Sources in my Game array and activates INotifyPropertyChanged. It all works out fine. I would just like to know how to implement, that the image should only bind if the image is loaded. Because as you see in the following Images there is a short period where no image is displayed. It's short but it is annoying. The ImageSource is an EmbeddedResource.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if you are using [Embedded images](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#embedded-images) or just [Local images](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#local-images) ? Local images is recommended .

What's more , there is another way to implement this function(swap the image by clicking the button).

1. Add a `bool` property in viewmodel.

   ```
   public class ViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private bool _isOne;
        public bool isOne { 
            get 
            {
                return _isOne;
            } 
            set 
            {
                _isOne = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            } 
        }
    }
   ```
2. Add two `Converter` for the two ImageButton .

   ```
   public class FirstConverter : IValueConverter
    {

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {

            bool isOne = (bool)value;

            return isOne ? "a.jpg" : "b.jpg";

        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    public class SecondConverter : IValueConverter
    {

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {

            bool isOne = (bool)value;

            return isOne ? "b.jpg" : "a.jpg";

        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
   ```
3. Create binding on the ImageButton .

   ```
   <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:FirstConverter x:Key="first" />
            <local:SecondConverter x:Key="second" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <StackLayout>
        <ImageButton Clicked="ImageButton_Clicked"  Source="{Binding isOne, Converter={StaticResource first}}"/>
        <ImageButton Clicked="ImageButton_Clicked"  Source="{Binding isOne, Converter={StaticResource second}}"/>
    </StackLayout>
   ```
4. Change the property in Button Click event.

   ```
   private void ImageButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            model.isOne = !model.isOne;
        }
   ```